# How can I reference a Git monorepo file from another Git repo?

Tags: git, svn, git-submodules, git-svn, git-subtree

I am currently trying to migrate an SVN repo into several Git repos. The original SVN repo can be interpreted as a monorepo since it features several independent projects. Due to Git tagging, I would like to break up this SVN monorepo into a Git monorepo and several project-specifc repos. Here is my scenario:

I have a Git monorepo call `Libraries`. This monorepo contains several single file libraries that are relatively independent from one another and hence need to be tagged seperately. Think of it something like

```
Libraries
    math.h
    math.c
    file.h
    file.c
    ...
```

Since I consider this a monorepo, I will tag in the following manner

```
math/1.0.0
math/1.1.0
file/1.0.0
file/1.1.0
```

Now onto the project specific repos.

I have a repo called `Project 1` that needs to reference individual files from the `Libraries` repo. Complicating the matter, I need to inject these library files into specific directories within `Project 1`. Something like the following:

```
Project 1
    headers
        math.h    // from math/1.0.0
        file.h    // from file/1.1.0
        project.h // project specific file
    source
        math.c    // from math/1.0.0
        file.c    // from file/1.1.0
        project.c // project specific file
```

So essentially I want the project specific repo to reference tagged individual files from a monorepo and I need to place them within very specific directories in the project specific repo.

Can I achieve this using submodules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submodule always means a subfolder in the parent repository.

If you OS supports it, you can then version symlinks for those files between:

- the specific folders
- the library submodule folder.

This is assuling you don't have *too* many of those files to symlink.

Comment: After researching this problem further, I came to the same conclusion that symlinks are probably required. Can you expand on your last statement "assuming you don't have too many..". Are you saying this just because it's a pain to manage them?

Comment: @Izzo Once in place, those symlinks do not require much management. It is just the installation phase which is possibly cumbersome if you have many of them: you would need to make a small script in order to automate the symlink creation process.